# Primefaces: Edit table element within a form & instant bean validation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

is there any CDI/Primefaces example that fulfills the following requirements:

- Data table showing entities
- Edit/Create panel form based on the selection and user choice (create new or edit selected)
- Instant ajax-based bean validation that prints the validation result behind the element (or all errors at the top of the form)

[My first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038115/primefaces-problems-combining-pdatatable-form-pdialog-pajax-valida) is not really successful.

Comment: Your task doesn't seem at all complicated,but your other question has a lot of code noise. Is all that code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately yes since I have a panel which is filled based on the current selection. I already minimized the code. The problem is: When client side validation fails and I close the form the entity seems to be blocked. When trying to call 'assignEntity' again (in this case of validation errors), this call fails and the last data is shown. Now, when I make valid inputs and close the form, all works fine. 'assignEntity' calls again.